# Index Error when adding multiple intances of a Date Picker dropdown in Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I found a datepicker on GitHub and am trying to use it multiple times in my kivy app to select a start and end date for data visualization. It works well until I add the second datepicker for the end date, then I recieve multiple Index Errors for List index out of range from my Picker.kv file and the app crashes after launch.

*edit
The problem is from the NavBar's default text, which for some reason ends up being out of range for the "Months" list even tho its set to 1.

***edited all to cleaner code + docstrings***

parent widget code

```
"""Analyzer data settings widget

Allows selection various parameters for data visualization
"""

"""3rd Party Imports"""
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.metrics import dp

"""Local Imports"""
from picker.picker import Picker

class AnalyzerSettings(BoxLayout):
    """Builds main widget in analyzersettings.kv"""
    pass
```

parent widget .kv

```
#: include picker/picker.kv

<AnalyzerSettings>
    ##Builds main box layout for AnalyzerSettings
    orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing: "4dp"
    
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: '25dp'
            text: "Data Settings"
        BoxLayout:
            ##Interval Selector
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: '25dp'
            Label:
                text: "Interval"
            Spinner:
                id: interval_select
                text: "1 W"
                values: "1 Min", "5 Min", "1 H", '1 D', "1 W", "1 Mo", "6 Mo" 
        
        BoxLayout: 
            ##Start date picker
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: '25dp'
            Label: 
                text: "Start Date"
            Picker:
                id: start_picker
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: [0,0,0,0]

        BoxLayout: 
            ##End date picker
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: '25dp'
            Label: 
                text: "End Date"
            Picker:
                id: end_picker
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: [0,0,0,0]
```

Heres the picker code

```
"""Calendar Picker Widget

Calendar Picker Widget is a dropdown calendar for selecting dates.

Composed of a Button which fills a BoxLayout, Button triggers DropDown.

Defaults to Jan 2020
"""

"""3rd Party Imports"""
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown


class DatePicker(BoxLayout):
    """DatePicker widget creates interactable calendar
    
    widget built in picker.kv (from el3phanten's github *modified)
    
    """
    pass

class CalendarPicker(DropDown):
    """Dropdown widget for DatePicker.
    
    Details in picker.kv
    
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """Creates instance of DatePicker and adds to widget"""
        super(CalendarPicker, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        date_picker = DatePicker()
        self.add_widget(date_picker)


class Picker(BoxLayout):
    """"Main widget - Button filling boxlayout which triggers dropdown
    
    Details in Picker.kv
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """Creates instance of CalendarPicker for Button to trigger"""
        super(Picker, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.calendar_picker = CalendarPicker()
    def openpicker(self):
        """on-press function for Button which activates dropdown"""
        self.calendar_picker.open(self)
```

And the Picker.kv slightly modified from Github

```
#: import Calendar calendar.Calendar

<Day@Button>
    ##Creates Day Buttons
    datepicker: self.parent.datepicker
    color: [1,1,1,1]
    background_color: root.color if self.text != "" else [0,0,0,0]
    disabled: True if self.text == "" else False
    on_release:
        root.datepicker.picked = [int(self.text), root.datepicker.month, root.datepicker.year]
<Week@BoxLayout>
    ##Adds Day buttons to a BoxLayout
    datepicker: root.parent
    weekdays: ["","","","","","",""]
    Day:
        text: str(root.weekdays[0])
    Day:
        text: str(root.weekdays[1])
    Day:
        text: str(root.weekdays[2])
    Day:
        text: str(root.weekdays[3])
    Day:
        text: str(root.weekdays[4])
    Day:
        text: str(root.weekdays[5])
    Day:
        text: str(root.weekdays[6])
<WeekDays@BoxLayout>
    ##Adds weekday lables to box layout
    Label:
        text: "Mon"
    Label:
        text: "Tue"
    Label:
        text: "Wed"
    Label:
        text: "Thu"
    Label:
        text: "Fri"
    Label:
        text: "Sat"
    Label:
        text: "Sun"
<NavBar@BoxLayout>
    ##Creates navbar for picker
    datepicker: self.parent
    Spinner:
    ##Spinner to select month
        values: root.datepicker.months
        text: root.datepicker.months[root.datepicker.month-1] #####PROBLEM HERE####
        on_text:
            root.datepicker.month = root.datepicker.months.index(self.text)+1
    Spinner:
    ##Spinner to select year
        values: [str(i) for i in range(1970,2100)]
        text: str(root.datepicker.year)
        on_text:
            root.datepicker.year = int(self.text)
    Widget:
    Button:
    ##Move back
        text: "<"
        on_release:
            if root.datepicker.month == 1 and spin.text == "Month": root.datepicker.year -= 1
            if spin.text == "Month": root.datepicker.month = 12 if root.datepicker.month == 1 else root.datepicker.month - 1
            if spin.text == "Year": root.datepicker.year -= 1
    Spinner:
    ##Change interval for arrows
        id: spin
        values: ["Month","Year"]
        text: "Month"
    Button:
    ##Move forward
        text: ">"
        on_release:
            if root.datepicker.month == 12 and spin.text == "Month": root.datepicker.year += 1
            if spin.text == "Month": root.datepicker.month = 1 if root.datepicker.month == 12 else root.datepicker.month + 1
            if spin.text == "Year": root.datepicker.year += 1

<DatePicker>
    ##Builds DatePicker widget, height must be set for dropdown.
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: "200dp"
    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgba: [0,0,0,1]
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    year: 2020
    month: 1
    picked: ["","",""]
    months: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    calendar: Calendar()
    days: [(i if i > 0 else "") for i in self.calendar.itermonthdays(self.year, self.month)] + [""] * 14
    orientation: "vertical"
    NavBar:
    WeekDays:
    Week:
        weekdays: root.days[0:7]
    Week:
        weekdays: root.days[7:14]
    Week:
        weekdays: root.days[14:21]
    Week:
        weekdays: root.days[21:28]
    Week:
        weekdays: root.days[28:35]
    Week:
        weekdays: root.days[35:]
    Label:
        ##Shows selected date at bottom
        text: "" if root.picked == ["","",""] else "{}-{}-{}".format(root.picked[0], root.picked[1], root.picked[2])

<CalendarPicker>
    ##Dropdown details
    auto_width: False
    width: "250dp"

<Picker>
    ##Button details
    Button:
        text: "Min"
        size_hint: 1, None 
        height: "25dp"
        on_release: root.openpicker()
```

The error:

```
 ...
      44:    Spinner:
      45:        values: root.datepicker.months
 >>   46:        text: root.datepicker.months[root.datepicker.month-1]
      47:        on_text:
      48:            root.datepicker.month = root.datepicker.months.index(self.text)+1
 ...
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Have tried multiple different ways of creating the instances, inside the .kv, inside the .py, created Picker subclasses in the parent widget .py and added to the .kv but always get the same errors when i add a second Picker.  Im pretty new with classes and objects etc but ive spent too many hours hung up on this now :).

Looks like this: [Closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZPWM.jpg) and [Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFDp9.jpg)
I would like to have one for end date below the start date.

**edit ive bypassed the issue by defaulting the spinners text to "Jan" as shown below but cant figure out why adding a second one messes up the original code**

```
<NavBar@BoxLayout>
    ##Creates navbar for picker
    datepicker: self.parent
    Spinner:
    ##Spinner to select month
        values: root.datepicker.months
        text: "Jan" #####PROBLEM HERE####
        on_text:
            root.datepicker.month = root.datepicker.months.index(self.text)+1
```